# Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9.3

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {}
```

I am getting this warning. Can someone tell what is the problem here?

> Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:': 'void (^ _Nonnull __strong)()' vs 'void (^__strong _Nonnull)(void)'

Comment: pls check   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623068-application?language=objc

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to disable Clang's -Wstrict-prototypes like so:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wstrict-prototypes" 
completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
{}
```

The same is with the handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotifications. 
This appears to be a bug.